# EC2 Linux MarkLogic9 start service failed

Tags: service, marklogic

I added an instance that is RedHat Linux64. Installed JDK successfully. Then used SSH to send MarkLogic9 installation package to Linux and install finished. When I start MarkLogic service the messages came as following. (P.S: this is my first time to install MarkLogic)

```
Instance is not managed
Waiting for device mounted to come online : /dev/xvdf
Volume /dev/sdf has failed to attach - aborting
Warning: ec2-startup did not complete successfully
Check the error logs for details
Starting MarkLogic: [FAILED]
```

And following is log info:

```
2017-11-27 11:16:39 ERROR [HandleAwsError @ awserr.go.48] [instanceID=i-06sdwwa33d24d232df [HealthCheck] error when calling AWS APIs. error details - NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

Comment: It says to check the error logs...... Perhaps you could share that information.. Also share how you installed MarkLogic(AWS repos or download) and if this is an upgrade to 9 from 8, etc.. A more complete story
 and background info will likely get you a more complete response.

Comment: yes ,i checked the amazon erro log .

Comment: OK.. I'm trying to help you out here and guide you on giving more of a complete and useful background so that people can assist you. That is why I suggested other things that you could put in your post. I think if you leave your question as it is, no one will likely be able to offer up much assistance...

Comment: sorry,it's my first time intalled marklogic. i got a Red Hat Linux at AWS.Download the Marklogic9 and installed. i checked the amazon erro log .ERROR [HandleAwsError @ awserr.go.48] [instanceID=i-06eecsd221d23342dF] [HealthCheck] error when calling AWS APIs. error details - NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors....is this log file?

Comment: Please add the relevant information to the ticket in a clear way so that all may read it and understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Source of Infinate Wisdom, I googled for "Install MarkLogic ec2 aws"
Not far down I find  [https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2.pdf][1]

Good document to read.

If you choose to ignore the (literally "STOP" in all caps) ***"STOP: Before you do Anything!"*** suggestion on the first page, you can go further and find that ML needs a Data volume, and that using the root volume is ***A Bad Idea*** (its too small and crash your system when it fills up, let alone vanish if your instance terminates).  So if you choose to not use the recommended CloudFormation script for your first experience, you will need to manually create and attach a data volume, among other things.

. [1]: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/ec2.pdf

Comment: thanks for your answer...and the linux enviroment's RAM is 1GB,can run MarkLogic service successfully?

Comment: Not really, no. The free-tier eligible EC2 options are very underpowered for doing much. In theory you can get ML installed and running, but you'd be way ahead to use either CloudFormation or the Marketplace AMI's.

Answer (score 0):

the size and compute power of the host systems runnin ML are othaomal o the deployment and orchestration methods.

entirely diverent issues.  yes you should start wit the sample cloud formation scripts... but not due to size and performance, due to
the fact they were built to make a successful first time experience as painless as possible.   you would have had your ML server up and running in less time them it took to post to stackoverflow a question asking why it wasn’t,

totally unrelated - except for the built in set of instance types for the amis (1) 
what configurations are possible v recommended o supported,
all large;y dependent on workload and performance expectations.

marklogic can and run on resource constrained system — whether and how it works *well* requires the same mythodology to answer for micro and mega systems ..., workload. data size and format, query and data processing code used, performance requirements, working set,  hw, sw, vm, networking, storage ... while designed to support large enterprise workloads well,
there are also very constrained platforms and workloads in use in production systems.  a typical low end laptop can run ML fine ... for the some use cases, where others may need a cluster of a dozen or a hundred high end monsters.

(1). ‘supported instance types’ with marketplace amis ...
yes these do NOT include entry level ec2 instance types last i looked.
the rationale similar to why the st dre scripts make it hard to abuse the root volume for a data volume — not because it cannot be done,
rather an attempt to provide the best chance of a successful first time experience to the targeted market segment ... constrained by having only one chance to do it, knowing nothing at all about the intended use. ... a blind educated guess coupled with a lot of testing and support history about how people get things wrong no matter how much you lead them.
while ‘micro’ systems can be made to work successfully —in some specialized use cases, usually they don’t do as well as, as easily, reliably and handle as large a variety of whateveryouthrowatthem without careful workload specific tuning and sophisticated application code —

similarly ,,, there is a reason the docs make it as clear as humanly possible, even annoyingly so, that you should start with the cloud formation templates —
short of refusing to run without them.
can ML run on Platform X with Y-Memory, Z hypervisor, on docker or vmware or virtual box or brand acme raid controller ... 
very likely —,with some definition of ‘run’ and configured for those exact constraints 
very unlikely for arbitrary definitions of ‘run’ and no thought or effort to match the deployment with the environment

will it be easy to setup by someone who’s never done it before, run ‘my program’, at ‘my required speeds’ out of the box with no problems, no optimization’s, performance analysis, data refactoring, custom queries.
for a reasonably large set of initial use cases — for at least a reasonable and quick POC, very likely — if you follow the installation guide, with perhaps a few parameter adjustments 
 is that the best it can do ? absolutely not. 
but it’s very close given absolutely no knowledge of the users actual application, technical,experience, workloads, budget, IT staff, dev and qa team, requirements, business policies, future needs, staff, phase of the moon.

recommend, read the ec2 docs.
do what they say 
try it out with a realistic set of data and applications for your use, 
test. measure, experiment , learn 
THEN and ONLY THEN worry about if it will work on. t2.micro or m4.64xlarge9orbclusters thereof .. )
that is the beginning not the end 
the end is never, you can and should consider continual analysis and improving IT configurations as part of ongoing operating procedures.
minimizing cost is a systemic problem with many dimensions —
and on aws it’s FREE to change. It’s EXPENSIVE to not plan forchange.

change is cheep 
experimentation is cheep

choose instance types, storage, networking etc last not first.
consider TCOA .  question requirements ... do you NEED that dev system running sunday at 3am?   can QA tolerate occasional failures in exchange for 90% cost savings ?  Can you avoid over commitment by auto scaling ?
Do you need 5 9’s or is 3 9’s enough ?  can ingest be offloaded to non production systems with cheaper storage ?  Can a middle tear be used ... or removed to novevwork to the most cost effectiv4 components ?  is labor or it more  costly 
instant type is actually one of the least relevant components in TCOA